# What species of tree is meant in the Dangun myth of Korea?

Tags: world-tree, korean

The 'Dangun myth' tell the story of Korea's origins. [Hwanin/Haneullim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haneullim) is the Supreme God, whose son [Hwanung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hwanung) descends to earth to a **sandalwood** tree. His son is [Dangun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangun), founder and god-king of [Gojoseon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gojoseon), the first Korean kingdom.

The first extant record of the myth is in the [Samguk Yusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samguk_yusa) ([Chinese Source Text](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E5%9C%8B%E9%81%BA%E4%BA%8B/%E5%8D%B7%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80)), the 'Memorabilia of the Three Kingdoms', written in [Classical Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Chinese) - the script then used in Korea. From the Haneullim Wikipedia we read:

> The prince arrived under the Sindansu/ Shindansu (신단수/ Hanja: 神檀樹, "Holy Tree of Sandalwood") on the holy mountain, where he founded his holy city.

It cites Dr. Lee Chi-Ran, The Emergence of National Religions in Korea, where we see the tree reapear in this line:

> However, she lacked a husband, and soon became sad and prayed beneath a Sindansu (신단수; 神檀樹, "Divine Betula") tree to be blessed with a child.

We read **elsewhere** that the tree is called Paktal Namu, as in Hyung Il Pai's [Constructing Korean Origins: A Critical Review of Archaeology](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=AKTaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=paktal%20namu&source=bl&ots=tigsF7hO6P&sig=ACfU3U3vNJYisA4phQf3JH_tZ4pK2V4kBw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrxZKp2dboAhVOBKYKHbSNBswQ6AEwAHoECAsQKQ#v=onepage&q=paktal%20namu&f=false), pg. 58, *"the old name for the sacred tree tansu (paktal namu)."*

Some claim it is the [Betula Schmidtii](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Betula_schmidtii), like Keith Pratt and Richard Rutt in [Korea: A Historical and Cultural Dictionary](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=8tdcAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA481&lpg=PA481&dq=betula%20schmidtii%20korea&source=bl&ots=dXg817jwKN&sig=ACfU3U1GnxQwjYl3cCWzPadHuUA6IhKfyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1z5vTztboAhUS7GEKHY22BY8Q6AEwEXoECAkQLA#v=onepage&q=betula%20schmidtii%20korea&f=false), pg. 481. Birch does feature in Korean shamanism, so much so that it was brought from the North to the South (where it doesn't grow), as recounted here in [Are All Warriors Male?: Gender Roles on the Ancient Eurasian Steppe](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Xd5bAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=birch%20in%20korean%20shamanism&source=bl&ots=501m1fFGpG&sig=ACfU3U2c14gKCvPOUUFte1843sNTDTUGOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj_unf2tboAhVCy4sBHVtVBqkQ6AEwGHoECAsQOQ#v=onepage&q=birch%20in%20korean%20shamanism&f=false), pg. 121, by Katheryn M. Linduff, Karen S. Rubinson. The Koreans were even called [the race of the 'sandalwood'](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=N3ldDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=sandalwood%20in%20korean%20shamanism&source=bl&ots=0_14_eruEb&sig=ACfU3U1n_THzBmoU5UywXUbtCyYaCtSHEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkucTN29boAhWSd94KHdR5AToQ6AEwGHoECA4QKQ#v=snippet&q=sandalwood&f=false), and the tree is considered the Tree of Life in Korean Shamanism, so identifying the correct genus and species should be quite important.

**So which genus and species is 神檀樹/Paktal Namu? The [Sandalwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandalwood) or [Birch ('Betula')](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch) genus? And which species of sandalwood/birch?** And which tree do the Korean Shamans use/regard as the 神檀樹?

Answer (score 2):

神檀樹 in Literary Chinese literally means:

- 神 (shén) : spirit / deity
- 檀 (tán): sandalwood / hardwood
- 樹 (shù): tree

Translating 神檀樹 as "Divine Betula" is not supported by the characters. 檀 (tán) would have to be substituted by 樺 (huà).